# WorldClim Variables to Maxent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, maxent

I downloaded the Worldclim variables, they are in extension .adf. I want to extract by mask using ArcGis, but when I do the process the new layer is not with the same information than orginal. In fact, I try to continue for transform my new layer in ASCII format to proceed in Maxent, but I get a table with extension .txt.

Comment: Can you point to the Worldclim variables and Maxent software you are using?

Comment: Thank you so much Tareq, but I fixed it. The problem was with the version of my Software.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend to download the data (the 19 bioclim variables I suppose) in a more accessible format (in terms of ease using common software / packages). GeoTiff should be fine. You can get the files from either [WorldClim](http://worldclim.org/version2) or [CHELSA](https://www.wsl.ch/lud/chelsa/data/bioclim/integer/). Note that the two sets differ as they are computed in different ways.

Then you can open and manipulate the files in ArcGis or R. To manipulate the whole CHELSA batch at once in R you can try something like the following example code:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)
require(rgeos)

layer_list_1 <- list.files(path = ".../bioclim_layers/",
                           pattern = "CHELSA*",
                           full.names = T)
layer_stack_1 <- stack()
layer_stack_1 <- stack(x = layer_list_1)

study_area <- readOGR(dsn = ".../Study_Area.shp")
layer_stack_1_cropped <- stack(crop(x = layer_stack_1,
                                    y = study_area))

for (i in 1:19) {
  writeRaster(x = layer_stack_1_cropped@layers[[i]],
              format = "ascii",
              NAflag = -9999,
              filename = paste0(".../bioclim_layers/",
                                names(layer_stack_1@layers[[i]]),
                                ".asc"))
}
```

Of course, you will have to correct the file paths in the example above. If you wanted to stick to adf please find the answer (again for R) in this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2008-September/004135.html).

Answer (score -1):

To transform you raster to ascii properly you have to write ".csv" in the name of the exported file.

Comment: This is not the case. First, the file extension for the ESRI ASCII format is ".asc" and second, it is not a comma separated format but, rather a space separated array with a very specific header. I believe that you are thinking about [x,y,z] triplicates, which are an entirely different format.